# cannot set UITablevIewCell textLabel text second time around

Tags: ios, objective-c

Up front: I am a noob.

I have a method which sets the text on the textLabel object in a UITableViewCell. The relevant code snippet is:

```
NSLog(@"BEFORE .textLabel.text: %@", _addWarmupActivityTableViewCell.textLabel.text);
NSLog(@"BEFORE activity.name: %@", theSelectedActivityToDisplayAndSave.name);
_addWarmupActivityTableViewCell.textLabel.text = theSelectedActivityToDisplayAndSave.name;
NSLog(@"AFTER .textLabel.text: %@", _addWarmupActivityTableViewCell.textLabel.text);
```

The first time you set it, it works. You can see by this logging:

```
[12231:c07] BEFORE .textLabel.text: (null)
[12231:c07] BEFORE activity.name: Animal Movements
[12231:c07] AFTER .textLabel.text: Animal Movements
```

Then, any subsequent time it is called after, it returns a null as shown by the following logging:

```
[12231:c07] BEFORE .textLabel.text: (null)
[12231:c07] BEFORE activity.name: Animal Movements
[12231:c07] AFTER .textLabel.text: (null)
```

I must admit that I am a bit stumped. I have read in other posts that (it could be) anytime the textLabel is modified it actually creates a new UILabel object. However, to me, that still doesn't explain why it is a (null) one line after I try to set it?

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint to see if _addWarmupActivityTableViewCell and _addWarmupActivityTableViewCell.textLabel look sane both times?

Comment: Make sure you're not setting the label within the block where you allocate the cell - this only gets called once, if using reusable cell system.

Comment: What is `_addWarmupActivityTableViewCell` and where are you allocating this ?

Comment: _addWarmupActivityTableViewCell is an IBoutlet, which doesn't actually get allocated because it is a 'static' table. Does it need to be, even if it is a static table.

Comment: @brizrobbo sorry to ping you, but i am facing the same issue.Is it possible for you to post the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing the code where you allocate/dequeue the cell, so it is hard to say -- I'm assuming you are allocating it somewhere before what you listed.

You're going to have something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = theSelectedActivityToDisplayAndSave.name; // wherever you get this from
    return cell;
}
```

Does that look similar to the method you're using?

I think what I'd be looking at is whether the cell is being properly allocated.

Comment: I should have mentioned that it is a static table. As far as my understanding extends, cellForRowAtIndexPath isn't applicable for static tables. Am I incorrect?

Comment: Thanks. This set me in the right direction. In my inexperience, I was making some assumptions that weren't necessarily true. Anyway, I re-jigged the datasource component of the class and implemented cellForRowAtIndexPath. It is working as desired now.